# Are there circular limaçons?

Tags: geometry, circles, conic-sections, curves, locus

Trying to get a general definition for auxiliary circles in the context of conic sections (Wikipedia redirects me to just 'Ellipse'), I came to [this table](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pedal_curve#Pedals_of_specific_curves) at the wiki for pedal curves. It states that for central conics, the auxiliary circle is the pedal of the conic with respect to the focus, and that similarly the tangent at the vertex is the pedal for parabolas (so correct me if I'm wrong, but there aren't auxiliary circles for parabolas).

Since the circle is a case of an ellipse, I supposed that its pedal was the circle itself -as stated [here](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/CirclePedalCurve.html)- and that the circle could be considered its own auxiliary circle. It makes sense; the points on a circle are the points you get for a pedal when you use the centre as the pedal point.

But then the table says that the pedal of a circle from any point is the limaçon. And even if I again use the 'focus' of the circle (the centre) as the pedal point, I just seem to get the squished shape of a limaçon, and not the expected circle.

I can't find any examples online of special-case limaçons that are circles, either. So is the pedal point I chose wrong, or is it that the auxiliary circle of a circle simply isn't defined as its pedal curve?

Comment: *"I can't find any examples online of special-case limaçons that are circles, either."* Have you looked at the MathWorld [Limaçon entry](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Limacon.html)? The general limaçon with polar equation $r=b+a\cos\theta$ becomes a circle when $b=0$.

Comment: *"correct me if I'm wrong, but there aren't auxiliary circles for parabolas"* For a parabola, the tangent line at the vertex "is" the auxiliary circle, albeit one with infinite radius and zero curvature. Thinking of lines as special members of the circle family comes in handy for unifying various results of geometry, so start getting used to it. :) For instance, see [Descartes' "Kissing Circles" theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Descartes%27_theorem), which holds even when the kissers don't look all that *circular*.

Comment: @Blue: On the limaçon formula; oh, right, sorry. I wasn't familiar with polar coordinates other than using them for complex numbers. Great example for the parabola, too. So the basic idea that a conic's auxiliary circle is its pedal curve from its focus *is* correct, right?

Comment: @Blue, I've posted an answer. Are the points about hyperbola auxiliary circles and the definition of auxiliary circle being a pedal for all conics correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As in Blue's first comment, the limaçon of a circle with $b=0$ is indeed the circle itself. (That the pedal curve of a circle is the circle itself can be seen by using the basic [foot-of-the-perpendicular equations](https://schooltutoring.com/help/what-is-the-foot-of-a-perpendicular/) with no hassle, too.)

The parabola's auxiliary circle, as in the second comment, can be visualised as an auxiliary circle itself; as the eccentricity of an ellipse graphed with a focus close to the origin grows closer to one, and one end shoots off into infinity, the part of the  auxiliary circle touching the visible end becomes more vertical, until when $e=1$, it becomes the tangent at the vertex. This line then flips(as $e$ grows past 1) to become the auxiliary circle for the hyperbola.

Thus, the auxiliary circle can be understood as the pedal of the conic from its focus.

Comment: +1. This is correct. ... It's a good exercise to show that the Cartesian equation for the pedal curve (aka, auxiliary circle) for a conic with respect to the focus is $$(1 - e^2) (x^2 + y^2)=p (p - 2 e x)$$ 
where the eccentricity and latus rectum are $e$ and $p$, and where the focus is located at the origin and corresponding vertex is on the positive $x$-axis, at $(\frac{p}{1+e},0)$. (FYI, the polar equation for such a conic is $r = \dfrac{p}{1+e\cos\theta}$.) From the equation, we see that the pedal curve/circle degenerates to a line when $e=1$ (ie, when the conic is a parabola).